# tensorflow how can I solve dtype conflict between one_hot and sign

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

My neural network has the following output:

- `logits` are outputs from tanh nodes, so the value is a float within (-1,1)
- `action` are the sign of `logits`
- `one_hot` are the one_hot version of `action`, with dimension 3 represents -1, 0, and +1

The problem is, my loss function is related to the `one_hot` values, so I build the neural network output part like this:

```
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs, 1, activation_fn=tf.tanh)
action = tf.sign(logits)
one_hot = tf.one_hot(action+1, depth=3)
```

and this gives me a TypeError of

> TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'indices' has DataType float32
>   not in list of allowed values: uint8, int32, int64

Then I tried to change `one_hot` to:

```
one_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(action, tf.int32)+1, depth=3)
```

And I got another error of no gradients:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph
>   for ops that do not support gradients, between variables [...]

Is there any workarounds that I could use to avoid both errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you defining your loss like this? This is very far from any usual output layer / loss definition and you should have very good reasons for doing things like having nonlinear activation functions in your output layer (normally linear) and converting logits to a one-hot vector like that (instead of using a softmax). I'm not sure the latter is differentiable, which may be causing your error.

Comment: @cheersmate there're different definition of return associated with different actions, and it cannot be represented in one formula

Comment: So you want to build a RL agent? Which RL training algorithm allows for having independent actions?

Comment: yeah this is a Recurrent Reinforcement Learning agent, I'd like to use gradient ascent on the sum of all returns

Comment: That's not an RL algorithm (like policy gradient, actor-critic, PPO, TRPO, Q-learning).